# Emails sent from PHP script going missing

Tags: php, email

On my website I have a contact form. When a user fills in the form, a PHP script saves it to a MySQL database and sends an email to me with the user's details. Usually, this works fine. However, occasionally the details are saved to MySQL but I do not receive the email notification.

I got the web hosting company to send me a copy of their log file and it shows that the email is being sent - here is the log entry for one of the missing emails:

```
2013-01-23 10:49:39 1Txxth-00046B-VL => me@mysite.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=b.mx.mymailserver.net [123.456.789.10]
```

This suggests to me that the email was sent, but is somehow not getting to us - what could cause this to happen? Presumably if there was an error when the server attempted to send the email it would appear in the log excerpt above?

I'm using PEAR's Mail.php to send the emails via SMTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was caused by the fact that these emails used the user's email address as the from address. This somehow blocked the being sent (presumably because the mailserver thought it was a spam email).

Changing it from being the 'from' address to the 'reply-to' address seemed to fix the problem.